# How to extract data with selenium from a website?

Tags: python, html, selenium

I'm trying to extract some data with selenium and python from a website.
Here is some code I use until now:

```
url = 'https://www.kicker.de/1894559/spieldaten/bayern-muenchen-14/borussia-mgladbach-15'
chrome = webdriver.Chrome()
select = Select(chrome.find_element_by_id('selOptaPlayer1'))
select.select_by_value('57598')
```

It is possible to open the URL, select the player on the website. But I can't extract some data from the player. I get the error that selenium can't find the xpath.
With google help, the issue can be with iframes. Now my question is, how can I find out in which iframe is the data located?

Comment: you can switch between iframe, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python), then you can retry your find_by, till you find what you need

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find below solution to select 57598 value option using `option[text()='Alaba, David']`

**Solution 1:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\New folder\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://www.kicker.de/1894559/spieldaten/bayern-muenchen-14/borussia-mgladbach-1')
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='selOptaPlayer1']/option[text()='Alaba, David']").click()
```

**Solution 2:**

Also you can use below code for the same :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\New folder\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://www.kicker.de/1894559/spieldaten/bayern-muenchen-14/borussia-mgladbach-1')
select.select_by_value('57598')
```